# Passing pointer to self

Tags: c++

C++ I have a window class, parent, that creates several tab windows, child1, child2, ect..
The parent window has member variables for each child window. I want to access child2 from child1 and thought I might be able to pass a pointer to parent in the constructor of child1 and use parent's pointer to access child2. I don't even really know how to get started. I have tried something like the following and it doesn't compile, starting with the line containing (*this).

```
class CParent
{
public:
    CParent() {};
    CChild1 m_Child1(*this);
    CChild2 m_Child2;
    ....
};

class CChild1
{
public:
    CChild1(CParent *pParent) {};
    int getChild2Number(return pParent->m_Child2.m_number);
};

class CChild2
{
public:
    CChild2() {};
    m_number = 1;
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help out with
1. Getting this to compile without changing up the structure too much
2. Advice on a better way to set this relationship up.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Did you write it yourself from scratch? Why don't you learn by reading a book?

Comment: Well, aside from anything else, your understanding of what `this` is is simply wrong.  `this` is a `CParent*`, which is what the constructor expects. You dereference it, resulting in a `CParent`, which is wrong.

Comment: As a data point, the thing you're trying to do will create dependency cycles (e.g. `CParent -> CChild1 -> CParent`). You'd be better off putting the shared state in a separate class and passing e.g. a `shared_ptr` to it to each of the child classes.

Comment: I would definitely recommend that you invest further time learning C++ language concepts and features especially encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism and standard template containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the initializer list for the children and pass `this`.  However, be aware that some uses of `this` are incorrect inside an initializer list (since the object is still under construction and some members will not be initialized yet).

If `m_Child1` needs to use `m_Child2`, you should put `m_Child2` above `m_Child1` in the class definition so it will be initialized first.  Then you can pass the `this` pointer to `m_Child2` like this:

```
struct CParent {
    CParent() : m_Child1( this ) { }
private:
    CChild2 m_Child2;
    CChild1 m_Child1;
};
```

You might consider passing just `m_Child2` to `m_Child1`, though, to make the data dependency explicit, to give a hint why `m_Child2` must come first, and to not provide a reference to an object under construction.  That would look like this:

```
struct CChild2;  // Forward declare the class so CChild1 can accept it
struct CChild1 { // Define CChild1 first because CParent uses it for a member
    CChild1( CChild2 &child2 );
    // ...
};
// ...
struct CParent {
    CParent() : m_Child1( m_Child2 ) { }
private:
    CChild2 m_Child2;
    CChild1 m_Child1;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several severe issues concerning declaration and definition syntax, member initialization etc. My advise is to keep going with C++ basics.

I suggest to use a dynamic storage for your children since your questions gives a hint that there may be more than two of them.

```
class CParent;

class CChild
{
public:
  CChild (CParent * p_parent);
  int get_other_child_number(size_t const other_child);
  int number (void) { return m_number; }
private:
  CParent * m_parent;
  int m_number;
};

class CParent
{
public:
  CParent (void) { }
  void add_child (void) { m_children.emplace_back(this); }
  CChild & child (size_t const child_num) { return m_children.at(child_num); }
  CChild const & child (size_t const child_num) const { return m_children.at(child_num); }
  size_t num_childs (void) const { return m_children.size(); }
private:
  std::vector<CChild> m_children;
};

CChild::CChild (CParent * p_parent) : m_parent(p_parent), m_number(p_parent->num_childs()) { }
int CChild::get_other_child_number(size_t const other_child)
{ 
  return m_parent->child(other_child).number(); 
}


int main()
{
  CParent par;
  par.add_child();
  par.add_child();
  cout << "Number of Child 0 is " << par.child(0).number() << endl;
  cout << "Number of Child 1 is " << par.child(1).number() << endl;
  cout << "Number of Child 0 from Child 1 is " << par.child(1).get_other_child_number(0) << endl;
  cout << "Number of Child 1 from Child 0 is " << par.child(0).get_other_child_number(1) << endl;
}
```